# Publish WebLogic instance to other computers in the same wifi network and/or internet

Tags: java, weblogic, wifi, weblogic11g

I have two laptops connected to my home Wi-Fi. One laptop runs WebLogic 12c server and contains a deployed application. 
I can access this application from the same machine using `<MyLaptopIP>:7001/myapplication`.

But When I type this address from the other machine connected to the same wi-fi network my browser shows me a "page cannot be displayed" error.

How do I make this work?

Also can I access this application from anywhere over the internet?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make one machine server (by creating home network) in this case. In this case your both computers are not in same network. they are just using same wi-fi network.you can google your query to create home network with your OS.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that the port 7001 on the machine that runs the server is open. Have a look at [How to determine if a port is open on a Windows server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273159/how-to-determine-if-a-port-is-open-on-a-windows-server) and
[How to know if a port is open or not in Linux system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029297/how-to-know-if-a-port-is-open-or-not-in-linux-system)